# How to set background image of span tag that background image fill background of span?

Tags: html, css, image

I try to set background image of span tag that background image fill background of span .

Size of span is variable.

Background of span Should not be repeated

```
<span class="link-shape" ></span>
```

css:

```
.img-rectangular .link-shape {
    background-image: url(images/icon-link.png);
    position: absolute;
    top:  35%;
    left: 35%;
    height: 20%;
    width:  20%;
    z-index:-1;
}

.img-rectangular:hover .link-shape {
     z-index:100000;
}
```

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the background-size property to achieve this

```
background-size: cover;
```

This will zoom/crop the given image to the size of the span. Or you can use the other variant:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

A good example and tutorial on this can be found at [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/)

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%;   : is best way.